# По каким причинам Spring MVC не распознает БД?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, intellij-idea, hibernate

Имеется база данных, необходимо подключить ее у проекту. 
Подключал ее при помощи spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.issartpractice.server"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="connectionProperties" value="org.issartpractice.server.entity"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dev2016"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL"/>
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect"/>
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="org.issartpractice.server"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>
```

Но DataSource в упор не видит БД. В окне Assign Data Source уведомляют о том что подключенных баз данных вообще нет.
У меня 2 версии.
1) Я что-то прозевал при конфигурации.
2) Я не настроил сервер баз данных.
Что ещё может быть?
[image: Класс сущности]

Answer (score 1):

Для конфигурирования dataSourse не требуется задавать connectionProperties, и dataSourse никак не связан с entity. DataSourse служит для настройки самого подключения к бд. Cтрока

```
<property name="connectionProperties"    value="org.issartpractice.server.entity"/>
```

является лишней, ее следует убрать. В классе DriverManagerDataSourceBase поле

```
protected Properties properties = new AuthMaskingProperties();
```

тут указываются properties для подключения,а вы ссылаетесь на пакет с entity.

Проверьте бд и подключение к ней, в комплекте с postgres ставится pgAdmin, попробуйте подключиться.

Так же я в своей работе использую

```
package org.springframework.orm.hibernate5;
```

довольно прост в конфигурировании.